# How to access network drive folder using credentials in php?

Tags: php, network-drive, windows-share

I am working on a php code as shown below in which I want to access network drive folder (music) using credentials in php. The credentials
is being set because I want to give the full access only to a particular user.

`$src_dir = '\\\INVEST-OP-001\test\music';`   // Line#A

The full permission/access of **music folder** is given to the following credentials:

```
username : 'mickeymouse'
password : 'helloworld'
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code at Line#A so that I can access the music folder using credentials in php.

Comment: On windows `NET USE Z: \\INVEST-OP-001\test\music helloworld /USER:domainname\mickeymouse`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing a Windows Share using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444976/accessing-a-windows-share-using-php)

Comment: @AbraCadaver Ok, I will do that. I am wondering what do you want me to check after doing it ?

Comment: You will be able to access `Z:` if it works and that's where the music will be.

Comment: @AbraCadaver What is Z: by the way ?

Comment: That's a drive letter you are assigning to that share.  So you can access it like `C:`.

Comment: @miken32 Is it really a duplicate ? I don't  think so.

Comment: @miken32 That question doesn't explain how can we use credential to access network drive in php.

Comment: You can't. That's what the accepted answer says.

Comment: @miken32 I think you can after reading this from here http://www.smorgasbork.com/2008/07/23/accessing-smb-servers-with-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This works for me:**

```
<?php

$user = 'mickeymouse';
$password = 'helloworld';

exec('net use "\\\INVEST-OP-001\test\music" /user:"'.$user.'" "'.$password.'" /persistent:no');
$files = scandir('\\\INVEST-OP-001\test\music');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($files);

exec('net use "\\\INVEST-OP-001\test\music" /delete /yes');
```

Comment: /user is /helloworld ?

Comment: like this `exec('net use "\\\INVEST-OP-001\test\music" /mickeymouse:"'.$mickeymouse.'" "'.$hellworld.'" /persistent:no');`

Comment: No, `/user:` has to remain as is. Final result will be `net use "\\\INVEST-OP-001\test\music" /user:mickeymouse helloworld /persistent:no`

Comment: What this command do `exec('net use "\\\INVEST-OP-001\test\music" /delete /yes');` ? It disconnects the connection established for that credentials ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, like when you disconnect a network drive in the Windows explorer.

Comment: hope all is well. I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56430459/how-to-convert-mp4-files-into-mp3-on-button-click-using-ffmpeg-php) I am wondering if you can have a look.